# Open CV addWeighted Error

Tags: opencv

Hi i am trying to draw some transparent shapes over a webcam feed.

I am encountering the error Sizes of Input argument do not matched. I have check my code and could not identify the fault

```
    double alpha = 0.8;
    Mat polarize(480, 640, CV_8UC4);

    Size s = webcam.size();
    double rows = s.height;
    double cols = s.width;
    std::cout << "Webcam R " << rows << "   C " << cols << std::endl;

    s = shape.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;

    std::cout << "Shape R " << rows << "   C " << cols << std::endl;


    addWeighted(shape, alpha, webcam, 1.0 - alpha, 0.0, polarize); // Error Here
```

I have checked that both Mat shape and Mat webcam is of the same Row and Column. Is there any thing that i missed ?

Comment: Mat polarize( webcam.size(), webcam.type() ); // not CV_8UC4

Comment: @berak Hi i have tried the suggested but the error persist

Answer (score 1):

You checked width and height of "shape" and "webcam", but not their type. If it is not the same (depth and number of channels), than the function will fail.

Also, there no need to initialize "polarize". It will be created by addWeighted() according to width, height and type of input images.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the webcam is copied from `cv::VideoCapture` object, which should be a 3-channel matrix.

so `Mat polarize(480, 640, CV_8UC3);` should work.